# Android: text doesn't appear in Button widget

Tags: android, xml, button, android-button

I am trying to create a Linear Layout with 3 Buttons arranged horizontally. Each button has a text and an image. It looks like this in Android studio:

[image]

But in my emulator, it looks like this on small devices:

[image]

As you can see, the text is not visible.
Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lightingButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#82B2C6"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/lighting"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Lighting"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plantButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#82B2C6"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/plant"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Decoration"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13.2sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#82B2C6"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bed"
            android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Bedroom"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe your issue related to the device resolution, try with another device

Answer (score 0):

I checked your layout. Just add this attribute

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

in your `Button`.
If not solved. let me know.

Comment: Nothing changed. The text still does not appear.

Comment: @Gloria you need to add any of one image to testing. because i don't know exact size of your image. If you add link of that image. It'll helpful to get answer soon.